# Modal window login form not working Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

This is the code i have for my Sign up form,it is located in my **views/devise/registration/new.html.erb folder**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#normalModal" id="secondtry" class="btn btn-success btn outline">sign up</a>

<div id="normalModal" class="modal fade" data-toggle="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">      
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h1 class="modal-title">Signup to sharebox</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <%= devise_error_messages! %>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %> <% if @validatable %><i>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</i><% end %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>
          <% end %>

          <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

the result is this little button 
[image: Button]

when i click on that i get the modal window sign up form as expected,the background gets darker,and the sign up form pops up.
[image: modal sign up form]

Everything works great,in terms of functionality.

> **Question:** how can i put this "sign up" button in my main navigation bar,which is located in **views/layouts/_header.html.erb**,(my application.erb file calls in other partials) ,whatever i tried the devise gave an "undermined method resources" or the the screen would go a bit black in the background as it should,but the form wouldn't appear.
>   *Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

Add in nav only your button

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#normalModal" id="secondtry" class="btn btn-success btn outline">sign up</a></li>
```

And then without button render in _header.html.erb

```
<%= render "devise/registrations/newfile" %>
```

Comment: yes,i have it there,and i created a new file in **views/devise/registration/_newfile** with the long code above,and try to render it in my navbar like this **render "users/registrations/newfile** ,when i click on the button,my screen just turns a little black,but the sign up form doesn't appear.

Comment: it works as it used to before,but how do i properly render it in my _header.html.erb file,right now i use **<li><%= render "devise/registrations/newfile" %></li>** ,it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: My problem,is that i don't know how to render it in **views/layouts/_header.html.erb** because the file itself is in **devise/registrations/newfile**

Comment: it works really good,but the sign up pop up,appears directly in the navbar "literally",when it should appear in the center of the page.i added your second code **<%= render "devise/registrations/newfile" %>** into my main application layout,as an experiment,the button appeared in the middle of the page,i click on that and it works as i want.but how to make the button be in the navbar,but the sign up form appear in the main layout.

Comment: here is a screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5t9h4txr0cizwq/Snip20150417_5.png?dl=0  as you can see the sign up form appeared in the header,in the navbar,when it actually should appear in the main layout,in the middle of the page.